# MS Excel - delete rows with value which are not in "criteria" table

Tags: excel, vba

I need small help with a "cleaning" in my table - I have about 10 000 rows, but I need just rows with specific text in column D. I have table with this "criteria", but no idea how I can use it. Criteria means about 17 specific words which I can find in column D. Can you help me with this? I think VBA will be necessarily. Also is necessarily left original text in column D (for next VBA, which I use :) )

Comment: Some example data might help? input/ expected output/ crtieria for removal? also have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: filtr is not good idea, because there is lot of rows and columns with a specific text and I want something more automatic...I try use "advanced filter" and pivot table, but everything is just for show...I need "clean" and than use clean table for next VBA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple code that will check colum A:A for values AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD or empty and delete rows without them.

```
Sub CleanTheMess()
Dim su As Boolean, cm As XlCalculation
Dim r As Long, v(), r_offset As Long

su = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable screen updating
cm = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Disable automatic calculation

'Only use used values
With Intersect(Range("A:A"), Range("A:A").Worksheet.UsedRange)
    v = .Value 'Assign values to array
    r_offset = .Row - LBound(v) 'Mapping between array first index and worksheet row number
End With

'Check all row from bottom (so don't need to deal with row number changes after deletion)
For r = UBound(v) To LBound(v) Step -1
    Select Case v(r, 1)
    Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", Empty 'Do nothing
    Case Else
        Sheet4.Rows(r + r_offset).EntireRow.Delete
    End Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = su 'Restore screen updating
Application.Calculation = cm 'Restore calculation mode
End Sub
```

It was in my stackMacrofolder so if you look deep enough you will be able to find original code somewhere.